# Load one Fragment at once when there are multiple fragments in a Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have an Activity which  haves several Fragments and am using PagerAdapter for organising this Fragments , i got to know when my activity, loads all of my Fragment's codes  also gets executed even when am at first Fragment at that time my whole codes of all  fragment 2 or 3 also got executed which are in the `onCreateView` of my Fragment so  can we stop this behaviour i want to execute this codes only when user selects that particular fragment

Comment: See this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133912/android-viewpager-update-off-screen-but-cached-fragments-in-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

you can limit your pager by calling this method default load number is 3

```
yourPager.setOffscreenPageLimit([number of pages]);
```

if you want just one page without preload try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34648361/4708874) by TejjD

Comment: ` final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);`  well tried this but still the same effect existing

Comment: try viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)