# Data does not reload automatically in a Fragment inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have **2 activities:** Activity1 (MainActivity) and Activity2.

**Activity1 has 3 Fragments:** Fragment_1, Fragment_2 and Fragment_3.

I want to change data of Fragment_3 according to action performed on Activity2.

My problem is that, I call Activity2 from Fragment_2 and do something there (in Activity2) and hit back to Fragment_2 and View Fragmnet_3, there are no change in data of Fragment_3 (Fragment_3' data should be changed according to action performed on Activity2).

But when I choose Fragment_1 and then choose Fragment_3, data of it is changed according to action on Activity_2.

I want I call Activity2 from Fragment_2 and do something there (in Activity2) and hit back to Fragment_2 and View Fragmnet_3, data will change.

How to do that?

Comment: sorry someone edit my question, I click wrong button

Comment: "But when I choose Fragment_1 and then choose Fragment_3, data of it is changed according to action on Activity_2." this is how a `ViewPager` operates. It keeps in memory 2 fragments, one previous and one next. See [Android ViewPager: Update off-screen but cached fragments in ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133912/android-viewpager-update-off-screen-but-cached-fragments-in-viewpager) for more info.

Comment: agree with @Sufian.. **And you can not force any fragment to refresh automatically**....!!

Answer (score 0):

in your fragment add this method this method always call when your fragment if visible on screen.

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
         if(isVisibleToUser)
                      {
                        //your changes here
                      }

}
```

Comment: "//your changes here" is Fragment_3 reload?

Answer (score 0):

i made it! Use BroadCastRecevier!

frament3:

```
public class MyFragment3 extends Fragment {
String key;
private TextView tv;


@Override
public void onResume() {
    //register LocalBroadCastReceiver
    LocalBroadcastManager lm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext());
    MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.action.sodemo");
    lm.registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

    super.onResume();

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item3,container,false);
    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_3);

    return view;
}

class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        key = intent.getStringExtra("value");
        tv.setText(key);


    }
}
```

}

Activity2:

```
public class Activity_2 extends AppCompatActivity {
private LocalBroadcastManager lm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_2);
    lm=LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_choose);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //send value to fragment3
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.action.sodemo");
            intent.putExtra("value","change");
            lm.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}